# Drawing selection in sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I need to be able to draw selection in a sequence diagram. I have tried argouml, visio, & visual paradigm to no avail :(

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Q4ekN8j_9J4Xh0OYy4iQCw?authkey=Gv1sRgCJ_2mcXun4qbVA&feat=directlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off chance "draw selection" means "model selection between alternatives",  you need to add a **alt** combined fragment to the model. I don't know whether viso or argo support it ( argouml [doesn't look promising](http://www.google.com/search?q="combined+fragment"+site:http://argouml.tigris.org/)), but visual paradigm appears to ([how to guide](http://resource.visual-paradigm.com/uml_diagrams/sequence_diagram/using_alternative_combined_fragments_in_sequence_diagram.html)).

Comment: yes that is what I am asking. Thank you for the link however I was hoping to use a different notation. I have a pic of the notation but I can't seem to add an image to my question.

Comment: That looks like UML 1 - putting a guard on the message. Most tools have moved to UML 2, which uses the combined fragment notation instead. You could fake it if the tool you're using lets you add kinks to the message arrows, but it would be better to use the version of the notation the tool supports.